# POMM Postgresql multiple schema and global class

Tags: php, postgresql, pomm

We are facing 2 issues, could you help us get this solved

1) how to point dynamically to a schema in POMM. Example i have a `public` schema which stores all the users details and the private schema related to each user. When user logs in the logic is to read the `public` schema, find the private schema number and redirect the user to his private schema - how can i achieve this in POMM  (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html). Inside each private schema there are multiple tables (example employees general data / employees salary data and so on).

2) When we have multiple schemas with same table structure (employee general  / employee salary data) we need one class for working with all schemas - now for each table POMM generates one class.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I tried to generate classes using of ScanSchemaTool. But it is generating classes only for one schema.
I have 
schema1
 table_1
 table_2
 ...
schema2 
 table_1 (this table names are the same for all schemas)
 table_2

I want generate classes one time for wotking with all schemas, because only difference is schma name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Pomm's model manager uses each schema like a namespace and does access relations using their fully qualified name `schema.relation`.

The idea here is to tweak the model manager so the schema can be guessed thanks to the `search_path` environment variable.

You need a `template` schema where all the relations in common in all schemas are defined. Generate the models, structures and entities for this schema only:

```
$ php vendor/bin/pomm pomm:generate:schema-all db_name template
```

For each Model class, in the constructor, just set the relation without schema information like this:

```
class EmployeeModel extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->structure = new EmployeeStructure;
        $this->flexible_entity_class = '\Test\TemplateSchema\Employee';
        $this->structure->setRelation('employee'); // <- add this line
    }
}
```

Now, in your code, just set the `search_path` environment variable like this:

```
$pomm
    ->getDefaultSession()
    ->getConnection()
    ->executeAnonymousQuery(
        sprintf("SET search_path to %s, public", $schema)
    );

// Look in the employee table in the given schema
$employees = $pomm
    ->getDefaultSession()
    ->getModel('\DbName\Template\EmployeeModel')
    ->findAll()
    ;
```

Every time you will change the search path, the `Template` model files will point to tables in different schemas.

Comment: after running this command php vendor/bin/pomm.php pomm:generate:schema-all postgres public
I'm getting
Could not load configuration '/home/ubuntu/www/pomm2/.pomm_cli_bootstrap.php'

Comment: Sorry I look into documentation of POMM2 http://www.pomm-project.org/documentation/sandbox2 and see that need create that file manually.

Comment: Yes, CLI needs it. It must return a configured `Pomm` instance whatever it comes from.

Comment: after I first time execute cli command,In folder appears an empty file with this name \PommProject\ModelManager\SessionBuilder, is it normal? And second question. I was using POMM version 1, but your advice is from POMM2 now I'm using POMM2, but can't understand how to get $session  Object. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this the right answer  for my question 
$pomm = require ".pomm_cli_bootstrap.php";
$session = $pomm['my_db'];

Comment: Yes, the examples are using Pomm2. I have updated the answer to make more clear how to get a Session from a Pomm instance. Using `$pomm['my_db']` is fine also.